# Use SPSS Value Labels in Graph

Tags: spss

I am trying to write syntax for a bar graph in SPSS, using GGraph & the GPL (Graphical Production Language, not General Public License) code. Everything is working correctly with this code:

```
 GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Propinquity MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO 
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE. 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: Propinquity=col(source(s), name("Propinquity")) 
  COORD: transpose()
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Think about your best friend. Where were they living when you met ", 
    "them?")) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent")) 
    ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.percent.count(bin.rect(Propinquity))), shape.interior(shape.square), label(summary.percent.count("Propinquity")), label("%"))
END GPL.
```

The final thing I would like to add is to use the Value Labels from my SPSS data set to label the dim(1) axis. Is there a GPL element or a function for the GUIDE:axis() statement that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See if playing with the output options can help.

```
SET TVars=Labels TNumbers=Labels.
```

Comment: Is this a general SPSS command, or is it GPL syntax?

Comment: General SPSS output command.